# R legend with different icons

Tags: r, icons, legend

For my graph I use smartlegend. I have a plot composed of lines and boxplots. Is there a way to use different icons in smartlegend, i.e. I'd like to have the "normal" color filled boxes for the boxplots and some simple horizontal lines for the other data.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the standard `legend` function? The following will produce a legend with 2 lines and 2 symbols

```
legend ("top",
         col=c(1:4),
         lty=c(1,1,0,0),
         pch=c(0,0,1,2),
         legend=c("1","2","3","4")
       )
```